# write a linter using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this messy php file

```
<?php
    return array(
    "form.title" => "Edit Profile",
    "form.section_photo" => "Profile Photo",
)?>
```

I want to write a linter using node.js. The first step I will do is use regex to find the length of the left block, and make an output to replace the old file.

Desire output:

```
<?php
    return array(
    "form.title"         => "Edit Profile",
    "form.section_photo" => "Profile Photo",
)?>
```

I'm stuck somewhere, how can I use regex to firstly get the length of each left block? I've tried `(\".*?\")`

Comment: may be I am wrong but the code you are using is PHP, the title say node js and the tags are reactjs and javascript

Comment: good, now what is the question?

Comment: @SagarV I removed react, that was a mistake, I want to write a linter that work in node.js.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `?` from your regexp. Should look like this `/.*/`
With `?` it mathches an empty string so your `length` will be zero